# Next button is not getting enabled after started a java process

Tags: java, batch-file, installation, izpack

I am developing a installer for windows based , I have written a batch file to install all the dependencies for my application.

After successful dependencies installation am going to install my application. Now here the question is after successful application installation i want to start the server(Its a Java process, it will keep running until you stop) automatically than starting manually.

Here after started the server as a part of app installation **Next button in the **InstallPanel*** is not enabled.*

This is my executable info

**executable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/install_script.bat" stage="postinstall" keep="false" failure="abort"**

Am currently using IZPack 5 version.

**Note : If I stop the java process , Next button in the InstallPanel is getting enabled.**

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Is your Java program designed to run in the background?  I.e. When you run `install_script.bat` manually, does it hang until you terminate the Java process?

Comment: Finally I got one reply, thanks a lot.Actually for this am going to start the Java process as window service using Apache Common Daemon utility.